# How can I merge or concatenate 2 or more *.3gp files into jaust another 3gp file?

Tags: windows-xp, merge, 3gp, video

In 2003 there was celular phones that record videos in the 3GP Format; I downloaded them to my computer; they were played by a software named Platform4Player by Philips. But now they can be played with Windows Media Player (WMP).
What I want to do now is: to join/merge or concatenate those 3gp files.

I am using Windows XP.

How can I do such a merge?
Someone can help me?

Isabel

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that file format, but try the following -

```
copy /B fileA.3gp+fileB.3gp combined.3gp
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the format, either, but I know enough to think this probably won't work, as most file formats of any complexity will have a header at the beginning.  Now, if you could strip the header from fileB first and certain data lines up just right, you might get lucky.

Comment: I didn't know if you meant making it in a DOS window; that's what I have done:
copy /b 2003_Miguelito1_20030222.3gp+2003_Miguelito2_20030222.3gp Miguito_20030222.3gp
003_Miguelito1_20030222.3gp
003_Miguelito2_20030222.3gp
       1 ficheiro(s) copiado(s)
It just creates a copy of the first file, with the same extension = 3gp.
The second file is not there. I have seen it with WMP, because with Plaform4player, it comes an error: Unable to open file(code0x7).
Thanks any way.
If you have any other idea, let me know it please.
Regards
Isabel

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn - it works perfectly for mp3 files

Comment: Unfortunately, the major part of the video clips (with sound) I have, are in these formats: 3gp, MPG, AVI, ASF, MOV and MP4. So, the first step is to merge all 3gp, then all of the MPG, .... and finally all together. I still didn't find any software for each of them. It would be a great help if this copy command worked with some of them! I already tried with 3gp and mp4 and it doesn't work.
I saw an answer for mp4 but it is a Mac software and I am working with Windows XP.

Waiting for another tip or experienced case!
Thanks in advance
Isabel

Answer (score 0):

FFMpeg will convert from 3gp to another format, and you can also use it to join the files together.

First you convert the files from 3gp to Mpg (which you can join together) and then convert the joined mpg file to a better format (smaller generally)

(you can use Bryan's joining method on .Mpg files, but not on 3gp's.)